# Grab focus to a JPanel in a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have a `JLayeredPane` with 2 layers

the first layer is a `JPanel` Wrapping an `Image`.
the second layer is another object which extends `JPanel` called ResizableRectangle and implements `KeyListener`.

I've overrode the `KeyPressed` method but it doesn't receive the `keyPressed` event and the method doesn't get invoked.

I've set the `setFocusEnable(true)` and  used `grabFocus()`, `requestFocus()` and `requestFocusInWindows()` but all of them return false.

I figured out when I press tab after the the JFrame loads , the `Focus` goes to the panel that I want , and the listener gets the events.

I've added a `KeyListener` to the `JLayeredPane` and it works fine but the problem is that i want to add listener to the panel not the layeredPane.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you put [Image or ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) then add to the JLabel [MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

then just to call

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        myPanel.grabFocus();
        myPanel.requestFocus();//or requestFocusInWindows();          
     }
});
```

Comment: I dont want to declare my Resizable Rectangle as a final object , because I want to change it ( Resizable :D ) .Therefore I can't use it in anonymous or inner classes such as your code in runnable.

Comment: @Bamdad Dashtban there nothing indicated that your issue(s) corresponding with my post, or my magic globe is out of battery, for sooner/better hepl you have to edit your post with short runnable code that shows ...